# Induced current and Maxwell's equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, maxwell-equations

A thin cylindrical shell is made of a perfect conductor (PEC) with radius $b$ and length $L$.

There is a cylindrical current source with a surface current density with radius a, so that $a<b$, and length $L$. The current density is uniformly distributed in $\phi$.

The total current of the source is given and equal to $I_S$.

The PEC envelope ($r = b$) is connected to the current source at the top end ($z = L$) and at the bottom ($z = 0$) by a thin, flat layer of PEC.

Between and outside the cylinders there is air ($\mu_0, \epsilon_0$).

Using $L,a,b,I_S, \mu_0, \epsilon_0$:

1. Find the current surface dencity of the source $K_S$.
2. Find the induced currents on the sides of the perfect conductor (PEC), internal and external.
3. Find electric and magnetic fields for $r<a$ and $a<r<b$, and check boundry conditions.

[image: Drawing]

My attempt:

I suppose the answer for (1) is taking $I_S$ and devide by $2\pi a$ so that $K_S=\frac{I_S}{2\pi a}  [\frac{A}{m}]$

About the induced currents I am not sure, if I use $\vec{\bigtriangledown} \times \vec{H}=\vec{J}$ does $\vec{J} =0$? I suppose not because $\hat{n}_{1,2}\times(\vec{H_2}-\vec{H_1})=\vec{K_S}$

In generel, which equations relate to induced currents and surface current densities?

I would appreciate any explenations.